# Run a method only once in paint () (Java)

Tags: java, methods, paintcomponent

Im trying to run a method only **once** when I call it in the `paint ()` method, but when I call it normally it just runs over and over.
**Example:**

```
private void someMethod ()
{
 System.out.println ("Success");
}
@Override
public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
{
 someMethod ();
 repaint ();
}
```

This will output "Success" forever, I only can output it once.

Comment: `paintComponent(....)` is called when the component is repainted, calling `repaint()` inside this method will produce an infinite recursion.

Comment: actually `repaint` method calls the `paintComponent` mehod. So when you call `repaint` in `paintComponent` it goes into an infinite loop. So it will keep on printing `Success`

Comment: Use a global boolean to indicate this method has already been called and check that boolean inside the method

Comment: Regardless of the infinite recursion you have, `paintComponent` is called whenever the paint manager deems it necessary, which can be many times a second. I have a feeling you are trying to accomplish something the wrong way. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The paintComponent method is for **painting only**.  It is not for outputting strings.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc I know, outputting a string is not the purpose of this, just an example of the objective

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write the same bridge

Try this:

```
public class someClass{
    private boolean hasDone = false;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if(!hasDone){
            someMethod();
            hasDone = true;
        }
    }
}
```